# RGB888 to RGB565 pins for an AL250

Tags: video

I'm trying to design a circuit which takes an RGB888 signal from another board and deinterlaces/scan doubles using the Averlogic AL250 to send to an RTD2660H. The AL250 *"only accepts RGB565"* but it has a section in the datasheet that has a mapping for RGB888 (section 7.1).

What I want to know is, am I understanding correctly that I can use the pins it's described from the RGB888 signal and just ground/vcc the unused RGB888 signals or is there a way/IC to convert from 888 to 565 before it gets to the Averlogic?

Here is a link to the [Averlogic AL250](https://www.semiconductorstore.com/pdf/newsite/averlogic/AL250_251.pdf) datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RGB888 representation uses more bits to represent your image. This means that your image will have a better color resolution. If you want to convert this data to RGB565 you will be effectively reducing your color resolution. This can be done by using the mapping in the datasheet you provided. The pin mapping provided in the datasheet is done in such a way that the bits with the highest significance from RGB888 are used and the lower significance bits are discarded.

Comment: In other words, don't tie the unused RGB888 signals to anything -- just leave them open.

Comment: Thanks! Good to note not to connect the remaining pins to anything else.